# how to create Multi Instance By using Loop In C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I Have a List<>. it is the mother List<> Bag. It contains more Children List<> inside so I need to create more instances based on number of child List<> inside mother List<>. Ref snap Below.
I can't create using loop . Any suggestion

[image: Ref snap]

//--------------------------------------------------------//
var DistinctCutlists = CutlistName.Distinct().ToList();

```
    public void NumberofInstance(List<string> NameList)
    {
        
        foreach ( var Cutlist in NameList)
        {
            List<ModelObject> (Cutlist) = new List<ModelObject>();
            (this is erorr )
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi and welcome. please don't post code as pictures but paste it into your question.

Comment: Sorry I am new user . I will do

Comment: What error are you getting ? Also you don't need brackets around your Cutlist variable

Comment: I just Used Brackets for Indication But it is not working Real time. any another method for creating instance .

Comment: you cannot use the name of the iteration variable for a new variable! Change the name here: `List<ModelObject> (Cutlist)` to something that is not already in use

Comment: its not 100% clear what you are trying to achieve here, but hopefully this will help you understand what you could do and solve your problem.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ncGMoY